# Adding ELSE argument to AJAX Live Search for "No results found"

Tags: php, ajax, search

Having finally being able to make an AJAX driven live search functional, I need help understanding how to add an `else` argument function so that when there are no posts matching the search query, the search box will display "No results found" or whatever text I choose.

**This is the code I have whereof the `else` argument before the `endif` crashes the site.**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_data_fetch' , 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch', 'data_fetch');
function data_fetch() {

    $post_search_query = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => -1, 's' => esc_attr($_POST['search_keyword']), 'post_type' => 'post'));

        if ($post_search_query->have_posts()) :

            while ($post_search_query->have_posts()): $post_search_query->the_post(); ?>

        <h5><a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h5>
        <span class="live-search-post-excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></span>

    <?php endwhile;

        wp_reset_postdata();

            else {
            
                echo 'No results found';
        }
    endif;

die();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to not using `endif` and `endwhile`, just use curly brakets `{}` to determinate if`s body or add` :`after else`else:`

Your problem is that you mix two syntaxes.

Read this to fully understand how to write alternative syntax
https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

```
    add_action('wp_ajax_data_fetch' , 'data_fetch');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch', 'data_fetch');
    function data_fetch() {
    
        $post_search_query = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => -1, 's' => esc_attr($_POST['search_keyword']), 'post_type' => 'post'));
    
            if ($post_search_query->have_posts()){
    
                while ($post_search_query->have_posts()){  $post_search_query->the_post(); ?>
    
            <h5><a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h5>
            <span class="live-search-post-excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></span>
    
        <?php } //end while
wp_reset_postdata();
} //end if
    
         
    
                else {
                
                    echo 'No results found';
            } // end else
        
    
    die();
    
    }
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the very quick reply. I'm trying to understand and thereby debug your code as it gives me the following error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)` Any idea?

Comment: sorry, just one ending curly braket left :D i wrote this fast without editor so i didnt check number of brakets

Comment: Okay? Can you please update the code since adding an additional `}` at the end still gives the same error.

Comment: Your update is done :) Try it...

Comment: Thank you, but it still gives the same error.

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)`

Comment: Sorry again problem is function  wp_reset_postdata(); between if - else... this function is belong at the end of if? try to check update again please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118355/discussion-between-sahasrar-and-harold-aldersen).

Comment: No chat needed. I'll seek advice from other resources as well. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Chat was estabished because community don't like conversation between two users in comments, like our case :D :D :D

Comment: Fair enough. In that case it would be more beneficial to post a working solution instead of inviting to chat.

Comment: Trying your latest version, it all works as intended. Thank you.